# Sed error "sed: unmatched '/'"

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sed

I have a file containing data with the following format:

```
{"parameter":"toto.tata.titi", "value":"0/2", "notif":"1"}
```

I make a change on the file with sed:

```
sed -i "/\<$param\>/s/.*/$line/" myfile
```

which `line` variable is

```
{"parameter":"toto.tata.titi", "value":"0/2", "notif":"3"}
```

and `param` variable is `toto.tata.titi`

The above `sed` command return error:

```
sed: unmatched '/'
```

Because the `line` variable is containing `/` ==> `"0/2"`

How to update my sed command to make it work even if the `line` variable is containing `/`?

Comment: Just use another sed separator, because your variable contains one. This is duplicate!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your `$param` or `$line` may contain / on it which causes `sed` to have a syntax error. Consider using other delimiters like `|` or `@`.

Example:

```
sed -i "/\<$param\>/s|.*|$line|" myfile
```

But that may not be enough. You can also quote your slashes when they expand:

```
sed -i "/\<${param//\//\\/}\>/s|.*|$line|" myfile
```

Other safer characters can be used too:

```
d=$'\xFF'  ## Or d=$(printf '\xFF') which is compatible in many shells.
sed -i "/\<${param//\//\\/}\>/s${d}.*${d}${line}${d}" myfile
```

Comment: Do you the angled brackets (`< >`) need to be escaped? And what does `${param//\//\\/}` does exactly?

Comment: @skamazin Probably they don't need to be escaped as they're not special chars of regex. It changes all `/` in $param to `\/`.

Comment: So what would you call that method of editing the variable? I want to do some research because I've seen this sort of syntax once before and it seems really useful albeit cryptic

Comment: It's just one of the methods of parameter expansion and is well explained in manuals like Bash's manual. See [Shell Parameter Expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html). They may be cryptic but we always get what we want in the end by `echo`-ing our lines first before processing them like `echo sed -i "/\<${param//\//\\/}\>/s${d}.*${d}${line}${d}" myfile`. All we care about after all is just the final form of the command.

Comment: You should note in your answer that constructs like `$'\xFF'` are bash-only (since the question is also tagged with **[tag:shell]**), and will not work in other shells, or even in bash when running as `/bin/sh`.

Comment: @ghoti I had noted that `d=$(printf '\xFF')` is compatible in many shells.

Comment: Hmm, true.  Okay, nvm.  I'm pre-caffeinated.  :)  +1.

Comment: This will fail if `line` contains an ampersand (`&`) and with various other combinations of values in `param` and `line`. It will also treat the `.`s in `toto.tata.titi` in `param` as RE metacharacters and so can match unexpected strings. You can't do this job robustly with sed, just use awk.

Comment: I got the same error message because of a missing `/` delimiter, I think it worths mentionning it. This was due to a `$` end anchor in a **Makefile**, just before the delimiter, which **make** interprets as a variable. Solution was to escape the `$` by doubling it: `sed -i -E 's/^foo$$/bar/' file`

Comment: @EdMorton Awk was better indeed. Also `jq` should have been the right solution for this case. Allowing use of other non-JSON tools because format might vary is a compromise.

Answer (score 1):

Check if your `$param` or `$line` variables have `\n` (newline), in my case, that was the reason of the error.

Answer (score 0):

i had the same error when i used sed -i.bak 's/\r$//' command in my ansible task. i solved it by simply escaping the '\' in '\r'. i changed the command to `sed -i.bak 's/\\r$//'`

Answer (score -1):

This will robustly only operate on lines containing the **string** (not regexp) `toto.tata.titi`:

```
awk -v param="$param" -v line="$line" 'index($0,param){$0 = line} 1' file
```

and will be unaffected by any chars in `param` or in `line` other than backslashes. If you need to be able to process backslashes as-is, the shell variables just need to be moved to the file name list and the awk variables populated from them in the BEGIN section instead of by `-v` assignment:

```
awk 'BEGIN{param=ARGV[1]; line=ARGV[2]; ARGV[1]=ARGV[2]=""} index($0,param){$0 = line} 1' "$param" "$line" file
```